# !Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm transferring a wordpress site locally so I can develop safely, I'm very new to all this and have come across this error, so if you could explain in simple terms how to fix then that would be very helpful:

```
!Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in 
C:\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\wp-content\mu-plugins\wpengine-common\plugin.php
on line 408

Call Stack

#  Time    Memory   Function
1.0.0007 - 247624 - {Main}()<p>
2.0.0014 - 251160 - require ('C:\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\wp-blog-header.php')<p>
3.0.0022 - 268032 - require_once('C\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\wp-load.php')<p>
4 0.0029 - 279728 - require_once('C\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\wp-config.php')<p>
5 0.0041 - 370928 - require_once('C\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\wp-settings.php')<p>
6 0.2186 - 13379696 - 4 -0.0029 - 279728 - include_once('C\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\mu-plugins\mu-plugin.php<p>

Location

1 ..\index.php:0<p>
2 ..\index.php:17<p>
3 ..\wp-blog-header.php:12<p>
4 ..\wp-load.php:29<p>
5 ..\wp-config.php:90<p>
6 ..\wp-settings.php:159<p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably show some code.

Comment: @smottt - from the filenames, it looks like it's all third party code, so I doubt it would be helpful. My guess is he's running it on an old PHP version that isn't supported by the code. (see my answer)

Comment: This WP Engine backup related question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516656/php-parse-errror-in-wordpress

Answer (score 8):

The problem may be in php configuration differences. E.g. I once faced similar problem, your situation reminds me that. It was caused by php configuration related to short `<?php` syntax which allows to use `<?` instead. On test envirionment `<?` works on production doesn't

Comment: +1 This is exactly the error here for wpengine's code, as in the question.

Comment: I had the same error setting locally backup site from wpengine:syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC) in mu-plugins\wpengine-common\plugin.php 
setting short_open_tag = On in the php.ini fixed it. Thnx

Comment: I ran into this issue today and the PHP Error Message is not so helpful IMO. Looking at the specific part of the file didn't help me either because I din't recognize that the short tags were the issue. 

I'm writing in to WPEngine now to see if they may change this for their plugins since there's no advantage of using short tags anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Either line 408 has an error, missing a semi-colon or something that's making the next line choke, or you could be using a super old version of php which doesn't support classes though I would expect that to hose earlier on. Could it be that you're trying to run a PHP 5 script on PHP 4?

The `public` keyword can only be used in the class context in php, maybe that gives you a clue. May be yo have mistakenly used it somewhere else.

Make sure all your braces are closed `{}`

'localhost' should work fine for the DB but other includes path should be correct.

You might be using `<?` instead of `<?php`. Try to swich to `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on or before line `408` in file `C:\wamp\www\KentVenuesTest\wp-content\mu-plugins\wpengine-common\plugin.php`

When the parser reaches the token "public" on line `408` it's confident that there must have been a mistake somewhere since it did not expect to see the token "public".

Answer (score 0):

PHP is complaining that the code has a syntax error in it.

Since it looks like you're only using third-party code, I would guess that there isn't actually a syntax error in the code, but more likely you are trying to run it on a version of PHP that is incompatible with it.

What versions of PHP are on your remote server (ie where it works(?)) compared with your local machine (ie where it doesn't work)?

I would guess you've probably got an old version of PHP on the one that doesn't work. Try upgrading it; the best would be to make sure that both the dev and live sites are running the same PHP version, but it shouldn't matter too much that they're exactly the same as long as they're both sufficiently up-to-date to run the code.