# PHP Parse Error in Wordpress project from a WPEngine backup

Tags: php, wordpress

I've inherited a Wordpress project and I am trying to get it set up.  I have zero experience in Wordpress and may as well say I have zero PHP experience.  So far I've managed to get the environment set up on my local machine but I am stuck on a PHP parse error which I cannot find a solution for by googling.  I'd like to at least get the existing project running on my machine.

When I open up my site locally I get redirected to $ROOT/wp-admin/install.php and I get this error in the apache error_log:

```
[Wed Oct 22 22:32:42 2014] [error] [client ::1] PHP Parse error:  parse error in /path/to/project/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpengine-common/plugin.php on line 788
```

Line 788 is

```
    public function disable_indiv_plugin_update_notices( $value ) {
```

and the surrounding code is

```
function wpengine_credits() {

        if ( get_option( 'stylesheet' ) != 'twentyeleven' && get_option( 'template' ) != 'twentyeleven' )
        return false;

    if ( !defined('WPE_FOOTER_HTML') OR !WPE_FOOTER_HTML OR $this->already_emitted_powered_by == true )
        return false;

    //to prevent repeating
    $this->already_emitted_powered_by = true; ?>
        <div id="site-host">
                WP Engine <a href="http://wpengine.com" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Managed WordPress Hosting', 'wpengine' ); ?>"><?php printf( __( '%s.', 'wpengine' ), 'WordPress Hosting' ); ?></a>
    </div>
        <?php
    }

public function disable_indiv_plugin_update_notices( $value ) {
        $plugins_to_disable_notices_for = array();
        $basename = '';
        foreach ( $plugins_to_disable_notices_for as $plugin )
                $basename = plugin_basename( $plugin );
        if ( isset( $value->response[@$basename] ) )
                unset( $value->response[$basename] );
        return $value;
    }

public function get_powered_by_html( $affiliate_code = null ) {
    if ( ( ! defined('WPE_FOOTER_HTML') OR !WPE_FOOTER_HTML ) AND !$this->is_widget ) return "";

    $this->already_emitted_powered_by = true;

    if(WPE_FOOTER_HTML !== "") {
        $html = WPE_FOOTER_HTML;
    } else {
        $html = $this->view('general/powered-by',array('affiliate_code'=>$affiliate_code),false);
    }


    return "<span class=\"wpengine-promo\">$html</span>";
}
```

I have a feeling it has to do with my PHP version.  I am running PHP 5.4.30.  Other solutions to similar problems suggested using

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is all of that code inside a class definition? `public` is only valid in OOP classes, not plain regular functions.

Comment: You can likely completely delete the mu-plugins folder in your local environment. They're being used by WP-Engine...which you're not using.

Comment: Yeah, this seemed to solve it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delete the mu-plugins folder in you LOCAL environment... the error you are seeing is a special plugin run by WP Engine on their servers for internal use.  It will, as you can see, fail if run outside the WP Engine environment.

Just make sure you don't delete the mu-plugins folder on the WP Engine server when you are putting the local environment back up to production!

Comment: you must remove the wp-engine code from your mu-plugins directory. AS WELL - you must remove the mu-plugins.php file itself. This file is not something required by WordPress and in fact contains the calls to the wp-engine code. (Technically, you could just remove the mu-plugins.php file and you'll be fine since the mu-plugins structure is such that WordPress doesn't read in sub-directories like it does in plugins.)

Comment: Wow - just spent an hour on this. Thanks!